# FromJSON / ToJSON when some of the fields should be parsed manually

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I have a data:

```
data MyData = MyData { a :: String, b :: Integer, c :: Bool } 
                      deriving (Generic)

instance FromJSON MyData
instance ToJSON MyData
```

In fact, I have many more fields in `MyData`.

I want to parse 1 or 2 fields manually because in `MyData` they're called slightly different than in the real JSON object, while still being able to have `FromJSON` and `ToJSON` or something like that. Is it possible? Or should I in this case parse all the fields manually and not use `FromJSON` / `ToJSON`?

Comment: Relevant: [Parse JSON with fieldnames that contain reserved keywords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410686/parse-json-with-fieldnames-that-contain-reserved-keywords)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the template Haskell [deriving abilities of `aeson`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.0.2.1/docs/Data-Aeson-TH.html). There is an option there which helps you rename fields. For example, say I want to rename the `color` field to `colour` in the declaration below:

```
data MyData = MyData { address :: String
                     , streetNumber :: Integer
                     , isApartment :: Bool
                     , color :: String
                     }
```

Then, instead of deriving `Generic`, I add the following

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Data.Aeson.TH

data MyData = MyData { address :: String
                     , streetNumber :: Integer
                     , isApartment :: Bool
                     , color :: String
                     }

$(deriveJSON defaultOptions{
    constructorTagModifier = \f -> if f == "color" then "colour" else f 
  } ''MyData)
```

Then my `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` instances have appropriately named fields.

Comment: by the way, is there a way to generate a list of "imports" or "imports qualified" with template haskell  so it compiles as if I were to add them manually?

Comment: @Orado Not that I know of. Maybe someone else will have an idea for that.

Comment: alright. is it possible not to parse all the fields in `FromJSON` implementation, but only ones I want, because others are irrelevant for me?

Comment: @Orado That happens automatically. If your JSON object has more fields than you need, the extra fields are just ignored.

Comment: You should probably derive `Generic` anyway; all sorts of other classes will want it for defaults.